# Adding ProgressHuds/ActivityIndicator in my sencha touch application

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

While creating native iOS apps, i used `MBProgressHuds` to display an activity indicator like view when request were sent to the server, received from server.

Now i need to have a `ProgressHud` (which is similar to `MBProgressHud` in my application). How can i implement this with `Sencha TOuch 2`. (I am using `Cordova 1.6.1`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the native MBProgressHud you can by creating a Cordova plugin, instructions are [here](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS).

If you want to do it all in Sencha you might need to do it yourself with something like a Ext.MessageBox with a spinner inside it.

Comment: Well, it should work for both Android and iPhone. I saw the example app, `orally` has a progress hud init. How have they programmed it ?

Comment: Ext.DataView.List by default will throw up a spinner when it is loading via a store. If you create a list backed by a store and an ajax proxy for example the spinner will appear automatically every time you refresh the list.

Comment: Well, i am passing some form data to a web service, so until i get the response i need to display an activity indicator. I am not using store in my application